# Why can't it apply flatmap and subscribe on the same RxBleConnection observable twice?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rxandroidble

As title,

For simplicity, if i want to execute twice read operation with **different** UUID :

(I know RxAndroidBle have provided a multiple read function)

```
Observable<RxBleConnection> ob = device.establishConnection(false);

ob.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(CHAR_WIFI_SSID))
        .subscribe(
                characteristicValue -> {
                    //2. then read Successfully here !!!!!
                },
                throwable -> {
                }
        );

ob.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(CHAR_WIFI_SECURITY_MODE))
        .subscribe(
                characteristicValue -> {     
                },
                throwable -> {
                    //1. I got BleAlreadyConnectedException error first !!!!
                }
        );
```

Why does second subscribe() get BleAlreadyConnectedException ?

==========update==========

i found the solution,
if i modify

device.establishConnection(false)  ==>
device.establishConnection(false).compose(new ConnectionSharingAdapter())

ConnectionSharingAdapter will do something like this:

sourceObservable.replay(1).refCount();

keep the last one emitted by source observable

Comment: I don't know rxandroidble. But I think what you want is `Observable.share`.

Comment: I think i found the problem.
It's BleAlreadyConnectedException...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribing twice to the same `Observable` will invoke subscription logic twice, which can be redundant at some cases or faulty like your case, where you are establishing multiple connections to Ble which is forbidden and got the `BleAlreadyConnectedException`.
as Dean Xu pointed out, you should multicast your `Observable` to prevent that. (you can use various publish/share operators)

Comment: Maybe i have to change my question...
beacuse i read different UUID ,there are two difference topic.
 it's not the case : the same topic and multiple observers

Comment: not sure I understand your meaning, but the problem is the multiple `device.establishConnection`, you can read 2 different UUID , it just the connection itself that cannot be created twice, thus you need to multicast the connection, and then create 2 separate topics from the same connection.

Comment: i just call device.establishConnection() once, so i don't know why i get this exception...

Comment: seems you apply the solution at your edit to the answer, anyhow, `device.establishConnection()` just creates the Observable not performing the actual connect, when you subscribe the Observable subscription logic is executed, and as you subscribe twice it was executed twice

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,
I also do some test, ob = establishConnection(false).publish() and followed by ob.connect(), then call twice ob.flatMap().subscribe() ...., it's ok, no any error...